# Loading icons from asset folder in a page in angular project showing 429 error

Tags: angular

In my angular project, under **assets** folder I have some svg icons. I need to show those icons in the dropdown list beside of each item. Here is my code to show the icons:

```
constructor(        
        private matIconRegistry: MatIconRegistry,
        private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer      
    ) {
        
        this.registerIcon();
    }
    

registerIcon() {
        this.matIconRegistry.addSvgIcon("1", this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl("assets/icons/text.svg"));
        this.matIconRegistry.addSvgIcon("2", this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl("assets/icons/text.svg"));
        this.matIconRegistry.addSvgIcon("4", this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl("assets/icons/select.svg"));
        this.matIconRegistry.addSvgIcon("5", this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl("assets/icons/radio.svg"));
        this.matIconRegistry.addSvgIcon("6", this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl("assets/icons/checkbox.svg"));
        this.matIconRegistry.addSvgIcon("7", this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl("assets/icons/date.svg"));        
    }
```

Html code:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Field Type</mat-label>
    <mat-select [(ngModel)]="field.fieldType" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
        <mat-select-trigger>
            <mat-icon svgIcon="{{field.fieldType}}"></mat-icon>
            &nbsp;{{selectedFieldName}}
        </mat-select-trigger>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let item of allFieldTypes" [value]="item.value">
            <mat-icon class="material-icons" svgIcon="{{item.value}}"></mat-icon>
            {{item.viewValue}}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

While runing the project in my local Environment, it's working fine and I can see the icons in the dropdown list. But when I deploy the code to the AWS Cloud, the code is not working and I can see the **429** error for each icons.

[image]

Can anyone tell me how to fix the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you seem to have wrong configuration for this service,
here's an update service
and here's folder structure
 [folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAGNi.png)

and output here
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1u1U.png)

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { MatIconRegistry } from '@angular/material/icon';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class IconService {

  constructor(
    private _iconRegistry: MatIconRegistry,
    private _sanitizer: DomSanitizer
  ) {}
  public registerIcons(icons: Array<string>): void {
    icons.forEach((icon) => {

      this._iconRegistry.addSvgIcon(
        icon,
        this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(
          `assets/icons/${icon}.svg`
        )
      );
    });
  }
}
```

for app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { IconService } from './services/icon.service';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material/select';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    MatIconModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  providers: [IconService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

FOR app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { IconService } from './services/icon.service';

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'app-icons';
  icon: string = 'soc-icon';

  allFieldType=[];

  field:any

  constructor(private _iconService: IconService) {
    this.field = {
      value: this.icon,
      viewValue: 'Text',
    };
    this.allFieldTypes = [
      { value: this.icon, viewValue: 'Text' },
      { value: this.icon, viewValue: 'Number' },
      { value: this.icon, viewValue: 'Date' },
     
    ];
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this._iconService.registerIcons([this.icon]);
  }
```

for app.compnent.html

```html
  <h1>hello SVG icon</h1>

  <div>
    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-label>Select a field type</mat-label>
      <mat-select [(ngModel)]="field">
        <mat-select-trigger>
          <mat-icon svgIcon="{{field.value}}"></mat-icon>
          &nbsp;{{field.viewValue}}
        </mat-select-trigger>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let item of allFieldTypes" [value]="item">
          <mat-icon class="material-icons" svgIcon="{{item.value}}"></mat-icon>
          {{item.viewValue}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
```